# Laravel belongsTo ignoring foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 models, User and Task.

Task.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model
{
    //  
   protected $fillable=['text','title','user_id','completed','created_by'];
   public function users()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
   }

}
```

and User.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
}
```

My objective here is to have every task assigned to a user so I can retrieve the name of the user that created that task.
The users table has id and name columns. The task table also has an id column.
So how can I get the name of the user that created a task using eloquent relationships?

```
App\User::first()->tasks
```

gives:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tasks.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tasks` where `tasks`.`user_id` = 1 and `tasks`.`user_id` is not null)'
```

Comment: you probably don't need to specify the 'id' in the belongsTo method in your Task model.  $this->belongsTo(User::class) should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I added this function to Task.php

```
 public function users()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
   }
```

I wasn't supposed to use 'id' as foreign key. And also removed

```
 public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
```

from User model.

Answer (score 0):

You said `"My objective here is to have every task assigned to a user..."` so I belive one task belongs to one user only. If that is the case it is indeed a [One to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship. You should call `user()` not `users()` on the `Task` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in your Task model

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

I saw the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) and Laravel uses `foreign_key` as the second parameter, not `primary_key` as second parameter